# How I can invoke rails callback from separated script with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, callback

I have a simple rails app with active record model and callback inside.

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :update_markers

  private

  def update_markers
    …
  end
end
```

I also have separated script which have access to my bd through 'active_record'

```
 require 'active_record'

 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({
   adapter: 'postgresql',
   encoding: 'unicode',
   username: 'postgres',
   host: 'localhost',
   database: 'myapp_development'
 })

 class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = “places”
 end

 Place.last.update(name: ‘My name’)
```

When I try to update values inside this script callback doesn't call. How I can invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to load your model inside your script `require [root]/app/models/place.rb`. Right now it looks like you are not extending your model, but just define it, so there will be no callback there. Rails autoload models, but your script has no idea about it.

If your script is fully separate from your Rails app, then you have no other choices, then just to duplicate your model callback. In your script:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = “places”
  after_update :update_markers

  private

  def update_markers
   …
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't load my model inside this script because it has more dependencies and i don't want to load everything.
I run my script when some event happened (something from another service ). This script must be located somewhere outside my app.

Comment: Does `update_markers` has any third-party dependencies?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, I'd like to invoke `ActionCable.server.broadcast`

Comment: How you want to make independent from Rails script, that depends on it? I don't understand why you expected, that your script will run a callback if you have separate script. If you really want to keep it separate, you will still need to make all needed setup. Require `ActionCable` and configure it in your script above your model

Comment: I have the same database for this script and app. And I expected my rails app be able to understand when the data from database will change and run a callback

Comment: Such callbacks are triggered by Rails itself, when you change object in code. It can't and wasn't implemented to track changes inside database server. Does my answers helped you?

Comment: You are welcome. I would really appreciate if you make my response as a valid with a tick for future searches